# pytest success at module level, not at project level

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have a flask app using pytest with Flask 2.1.1, pytest 6.2.5.

In my tests/conftest.py, I have:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::DeprecationWarning')
def app():
    _app = create_app()
    _app.config.from_object(os.environ['TEST_SETTINGS'])
    with Postgresql() as postgresql:
        _app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = postgresql.url()
        ctx = _app.app_context()
        ctx.push()

        yield _app

        ctx.pop()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def db(app):
    _db.app = app
    _db.create_all()

    yield _db

    _db.drop_all()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session(db):
    connection = db.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
    session_ = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

    db.session = session_
    yield session_

    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
    session_.remove()
```

Then, I create fixtures: one per table and each builds upon the previous one

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def building(session):
    dragon = Building('173 Dragoon Ln.', 'Some place', 'SC', '79920', 'US')
    firstst = Building('312 First St.', 'Some place', 'GA', '31328', 'US')
    waterst = Building('50 Water St.', 'Some place', 'NJ', '07701', 'US')

    session.add(dragon)
    session.add(firstst)
    session.add(waterst)
    session.commit()

    yield session


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def group(building):
    session = building

    johnson = Group('Johnson', 1)
    simmons = Group('Simmons', 2)
    jamieson = Group('Jamieson', 3)

    session.add(johnson)
    session.add(simmons)
    session.add(jamieson)
    session.commit()

    yield session
```

etc...

Then in `tests/test_db.py`, I test the first table:

```
def test_building(building):
    session = building
    testbuil = session.query(Building).filter(Building.state_ == 'SC').one()
    assert testbuil.address_ == '173 Dragoon Ln.'

    testbuil = session.query(Building).filter(Building.country == 'US').all()
    assert len(testbuil) == 3
```

Then test the second table...

```
def test_group(group):
    session = group

    testgrp = session.query(Group).filter(Group.name_== 'Johnson').one()
    assert testgrp.building_id == 1

    records = session.query(Building).join(Group, Group.building_id == Building.id).all()
    assert len(records) == 3
```

...and continue like that.

When I call `pytest tests/test_db.py` from the project dir, all tests pass. My problem is that when I call only `pytest` from the same dir, tests fail or have errors.

```
FAILED tests/test_db.py::test_building - sqlalchemy.exc.MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found when exactly one was required
ERROR tests/test_db.py::test_group - sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" of relation "group" violates not-null constraint
```

Should I expect the same result for both calls?

Layout:

```
 /project
    ├── Procfile
    ├── README.md
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── config.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── myapp
    ├── pytest.ini
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── setup.cfg
    ├── tests
    │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── conftest.py
    │   └── test_configs.py
    │   └── test_db.py
    └── venvn
```

Comment: sounds like you you're not cleaning up the DB after each test

Comment: My session fixture should do that, no?

Comment: it add the DB entries, but it doesn't take them out

Comment: Ah, you mean in each fixture where I add db items, I need to remove them after yielding the session, correct?

Comment: And can I assume the answer to my original question is that I *should* expect the same result from those two commands?